# Fetch value from column name in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
val=$(curl https://www.geeksforgeeks.org | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -s [[:space::]] | grep -E client_id -e publication_id)
```

I have a requirement to fetch the particular value from curl command:

```
Sample I/P:
client_id:"15647",publication_id:["151","152","153"]
```

Output:

publication_id:["151,"152","153"]

I want to use grep command to fetch publication_id values from curl command in unix and store in variable

Comment: If the output is JSON, use `jq`

Comment: You must show us what you have tried

Comment: jq is not supporting in bash. Any other solution?

Comment: I have tried various grep command to fetch but unable to do

Comment: The http string used is just a sample in curl command

Comment: Give a real example, and what you have tried

Comment: And this is not faisable with Curl, as far as the HTML matching `client_id` is JS generated

Comment: Install `jq` on your system.

Comment: we cannot install anything in vdi because its restricted.. Can you provide alternative solution

Comment: Use python or perl to parse json.

Comment: Please take care of my comment, **this is generated by JS**. NoGo. Need https://pptr.dev or Selenium (javascript aware library)

Comment: I wanted to do by unix..If there is any approach can you please tell me

Comment: See: [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955505/3776858)

Comment: **it"s not possible to parse this JSON with unix tools as far as it's generated by javascript**

Answer (score 1):

One solution with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer), as said in comments, you need a [js](/questions/tagged/js) aware tool:

Javascript `wget.js` code (this is only to mimic `wget`, it's output only HTML, and the one generated by [js](/questions/tagged/js) too):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    var url = process.argv[2];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);
    console.log(html);
    browser.close();
})()
```

code:

```bash
node wget.js 'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org' |
    xidel -e '//div[@id="g_id_onload"]/@data-client_id'
```

Output:

```
388036620207-3uolk1hv6ta7p3r9l6s3bobifh086qe1.apps.googleusercontent.com
```